# combine two OCG filters in Openlayers : ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer

Tags: openlayers-2, filter

**i need to combine two OCG filters. each one works fine separably but if i combine them using Filter.Logical.OR, the first one works only.**

```
var c_filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({ 
type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR, 
filters: [ 
new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({ 
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO, 
    matchCase:false, 
    property: 'id', 
    value:(document.getElementById("Text")).value     
    }),   
new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({ 
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LIKE, 
    matchCase:false, 
    property: 'name', 
    value: "*" +(document.getElementById("Text")).value + "*"   
    })  
    ] 
});
```

**as you can see, the first one expect integer and the other one a string.
also i tried:**

```
var id_filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({ 
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO, 
    matchCase:false, 
    property: 'id', 
    value:(document.getElementById("searchText")).value     
    });   
var name_filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({ 
    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.LIKE, 
    matchCase:false, 
    property: 'name', 
    value: "*" +(document.getElementById("searchText")).value + "*"   
    });     

var orFilter = new Array(); 
orFilter.push(id_filter); 
orFilter.push(name_filter); 



wfsProtocol.read({             
    filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({ 
                 type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR, 
                 filters: orFilter 
             }),        
    callback: processTheQuery, 
    scope: strategy 
         })
```

**and still, the id_filter works fine. but the name_filter i got the error: 
ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "test name" 
i don't understand why it should be integer !! 
and if i try name_filter alone, it works fine !**

Comment: What about if you add the name_filter in array before the id_filter, do you get the same message ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace

`value: "*" +(document.getElementById("searchText")).value + "*"`

with

`value: "%" +(document.getElementById("searchText")).value + "%"`

I think you are using wrong wildcards, thats the problem

EDIT

Oops, also try to remove the extra `()`

Try this

`value: "%" +document.getElementById("searchText").value + "%"`